# how to consume a soap web service and display the data in my windows phone application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am building my first app for windows application. My requirement is that- On clicking a button i want to navigate to another page and in that page i want the data to be displayed directly from a soap web service also by performing xml parsing.

Button event code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient();
    client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
}

void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

I am not getting any result from here. Can anyone please help. I want to extract 3 text fields and 1 image from this web method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your web service. Your code is perfect but you need to change your web service. Donot return string from your web method but return the xml

Answer (score 1):

You had associate the delegate but you have not called the method. You probably have a method like

`KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient.DoSomethingAsync()`

This will fire the event and after that it will trigger the `client_getarvindNewsCompleted` method when the responde from the WebService comes.

**Edit**
Just remember to use the `[WebMethod]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in you WebService method.

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public string getarvindNews()
    {
       return "I am a string";
    }
}
```

In you code you call this async like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient client = new arvindSoapClient();
    client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new 
        EventHandler<getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);

    //Call the method async and get its result in client_getarvindNewsCompleted
    client.getarvindNewsAsync();
}

void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your `KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient` has a method right? Is ti shown in intellisense (when you start type its name)? It is a WCF Application?

Comment: Its done finally. Actlually there was some problem in webmethod as the same method which worked in android apps doesnot work in windows app. aslight modification was required

Comment: There was a problem in the Web Service. Actlually the web service that was already built worked fine with android and iphone app. But in Windows app we need to change it a little. It has to be returned as a string for windows app